# why wont it recognize the @properties from header file from main file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, syntax-error

**UIView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIView : UIResponder {
    IBOutlet UILabel *endLabel;
    IBOutlet UIButton *goButton;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textBox1;
    IBOutlet UITextField *textBox2;

    @property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *endLabel;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *goButton;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textBox1;
    @property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textBox2;
}
- (IBAction)goButtonClicked;
@end
```

**UIView.m**

```
#import "UIView.h"

@implementation UIView

@synthesize textBox1, goButton;
@synthesize textBox2, goButton;
@synthesize textBox1, endLabel;
@synthesize textBox2, endLabel;
@synthesize goButton, endLabel;

- (IBAction)goButtonClicked {

}

@end
```

Comment: As mentioned in my post; you are trying to reimplement UIView; this is obviously no good, as that class already and quite definitely exists. You need to rename your class and implement it as a subclass to UIView (e.g. MyView, although more descriptive names are generally preferred)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going a bit crazy with the `@synthesize`s, are we? I do believe that your main problem here is that `@property` declarations need to be **after** the closing } of `@interface`.

I'm surprised the compiler didn't throw up a red flag the size of Greenland, tho'.

Additionally, you probably meant to make a custom subclass of `UIView`; I'll use `MyView`.

```
//MyView.m -- correct synthesize declaration
@synthesize textBox1, goButton, textBox2, endLabel;

//MyView.h -- correct interface declaration
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyView : UIView {
  IBOutlet UILabel *endLabel;
  IBOutlet UITextField *textBox1;
  IBOutlet UITextField *textBox2;
  IBOutlet UIButton *goButton;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIButton *goButton;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UILabel *endLabel;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textBox1;
@property(nonatomic, retain) UITextField *textBox2;

@end
```

Comment: Yeah actually i had them out of it and it still wont work! i put them in there just to see what would happen...

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're naming your class UIView, which already exists in UIKit. See *@Williham's* advice on resolving this.

You only need one `@synthesize` per property, and when the property name matches the instance variable name, you should only need to do something like this in your .m file:

```
@synthesize endLabel;
@synthesize goButton;
@synthesize textBox1;
@synthesize textBox2;
```

Also, you're likely to run into problems getting your `IBAction` method to work. To use a method for a target-action linkage, it must have a return type of `IBAction` (which you have correct) and accept an `id` parameter representing the sender. The canonical method signature looks like this:

```
- (IBAction) goButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

I'd actually recommend a method name that's not explicitly tied to the button that invokes it, especially since there could be other ways to invoke the same action. (For example, if you were writing a desktop application, a key equivalent or menu command could do the same thing.)